# ng-repeat angularjs 1.5.11 not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat, jsfiddle

i have an **angularJS v1.5.11** app,
but i've got big problem when i want to do a simple ng-repeat in table like

```
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="score in data.result"> 
    <td ng-repeat="item in score"> {{ item }} </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

my code works fine on **angularJS v1.1.1**,
hope you can help me.
i made a JSFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/vpLj20w1/5/
u can change AngularJS framework version in JSFiddle to see work fine on 1.1.1, but on 1.4.8 and higher doesn't work..

best regards,
Axel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell angularjs that your controller exists. Try declaring a module and adding the controller to the module:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="scoreCtrl">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

and then add to your javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("scoreCtrl", scoreCtrl);
```

Now it runs better than it did, but you have a problem with `ng-repeat="item in score"` as angularjs needs a unique key for anything used in ng-repeat and you have duplicated items.

Change the inner loop to:

```
<td ng-repeat="item in score track by $index"> {{ item }} </td>
```

and now you should get the expected output.

BTW, looking at the javascript console in your browser would have helped you here: initially it was complaining that it couldn't find the controller function and then when I injected it into the app it complained about the repeater.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't injected your controller into the app. I can't explain why your example works on 1.1.1, as I only have experience on 1.4.x+, but you need to use the module controller injection.

https://jsfiddle.net/vpLj20w1/7/

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('scoreCtrl', scoreCtrl);
```

And give your ng-app a name (I used `app`)